# WPF, TextBlock Rotation, Alignment Issues

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, textblock

[image]I would like to rotate the TextBlock based on the text's center point [Horizontal and vertical). I have tried the following code. it is always taking topleft corner of the textblock. How to change it to center of the text itself.

```
<TextBlock Name="textBlock1"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="25" Foreground="#FFF63AFF" FontWeight="Bold"> 
TextBlock 
   <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
       <TransformGroup>
           <RotateTransform Angle="45" /> 
       </TransformGroup>   
   </TextBlock.RenderTransform>  
</TextBlock>
```

***Image Description:*** Textblock is part of canvas and textblock should rotate based on the intersection as shown in the image

I have tried HorizontalAlignment as well as VerticalAlignment too, actually it is taking parent's alignment details.

Do I need to get the actual width and actual height, then based on that details calculate the center point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5"

```
   <Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="25" Foreground="#FFF63AFF" FontWeight="Bold"> 
            TextBlock
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="45" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Awesome, but now I want to move the center to a certain point say (0,0) or (10,5) how to do it? TranslateTransform use relative values only

Comment: see center point is defined in rendertransform origin, which takes value in percentage, so if you want to place center at left top position your center is 0,0 for top right corner its 1,0 and if you set center as 2,0 it will be at right top corner + width of control. I hope i am able to describe it as putting all this in word is very difficult

Comment: Heena, please look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000804/wpf-textblock-translation-based-on-reference-point

Answer (score 0):

add the proprety in textbox :

```
TextAlignment="Center"
```

this is for horizontal alignement

Comment: nope, it will take parent's width for alignment, not textblock itself

Comment: sorry I dont understand what you mean exactly. Can you show me the code exactly??

Comment: mister, Please check the image description now