# WPF Textblock translation based on reference point

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, textblock

Please check the attached image. I made the textblock origin to it's center by RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5". Now I would like to move the textblock based on the reference point. May be (0,0 ) or (10,10) or ...... These are absolute points. For example, in case of (0,0) the textblock should move to absolute (0,0) based on its reference point. I know how to move relatively by TranslateTransform, but this case I need absolute transform.

[image]

Comment: Do you expect the `TextBlock`'s position to move at runtime (requiring a re-calc of its render transform), or would it be just a one-time move when the Window / TextBlock first loads?

Comment: @McGarnagle, Actually the collection of text is coming dynamically from a datasource, I need to position the text it dynamically after window loads (For example, simple case, If the user enter the text and location in a textbox, it should be displayed in the canvas based on the input)

Comment: Btw why this process is so complex in WPF? I am from winform side and getting my head around WPF now :-)

Comment: Actually, it could be that there is an easier way to get where you're going, using panels or something (for example, to give elements an absolute position, normally you should use a Canvas).  In other words, you may have posed an "XY problem", as they say.  My answer definitely seems like an overly-complex hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need this

```
void MoveToPoint(UIElement sender, Point point)
{
    Canvas.SetLeft(sender, point.X - sender.RenderTransformOrigin.X * sender.ActualWidth);
    Canvas.SetTop(sender, point.Y - sender.RenderTransformOrigin.Y * sender.ActualHeight);
}
```

to Xaml (patern MVVM):
you need write converter and for properties Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top use Binding. It's more code than previously.

Example Converter (example 6) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29054/WPF-Data-Binding-Part

In converter need send 2 parameters sender.RenderTransformOrigin.X and ActualWidth.

Watch Converter with some params (in russian) - http://habrahabr.ru/post/141107/

Comment: @@m4a, It is an wonderful solution, I will modify the answer depend on my requirement, but could you please explain how to integrate this solution to XAML, If I want to move all the lements to certain point?

Comment: Excellent, Actually I am following MVVM pattern.I have Google translate :P. Thank you very much

Comment: @@m4a, say for example, normally I can get to know ActualWidth of UIElement after placing the control to canvas only. In case, if I want to place the control directly to a certain point, hw to do it?

Answer (score 1):

> the textblock should move to absolute (0,0)

I assume that by "absolute" you mean "relative to the MainWindow".  I don't think there's a built-in render transform to coordinates relative to another element.  But, you could always use a binding for `X` and `Y` -- I guess it would have to be a MultiBinding to allow you to convert a) the MainWindow, b) the TextBlock, to the "relative" offset corresponding to an absolute coordinate in the MainWindow.

The XAML should be something like this (X coordinate only here, for example).  You could specify the target "absolute" point in the `ConverterParameter`:

```
<TextBlock Text="TextBlock" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform>
            <TranslateTransform.X>
                <MultiBinding>
                    <MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
                        <Point X="10" Y="10" />
                    </MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <converters:TranslateConverter />
                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}" />
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBlock}" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TranslateTransform.X>
        </TranslateTransform>
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
```

The "TranslateConverter" is where you convert your reference (the window) and target (the TextBlock) to a relative offset.  Use [`TransformToVisual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.transformtovisual%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert the coordinates of the TextBlock to those of the Window.

```
public class TranslateConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var window = values[0] as Window;
        var textblock = values[1] as TextBlock;
        Point absolutePoint = (parameter as Point?) ?? new Point(0, 0);

        // convert the target point from the Window's coordinates to the TextBlock's coordinates
        var generalTransform = window.TransformToVisual(textblock);
        Point offset = generalTransform.Transform(absolutePoint);

        // get the position of the RenderTransform origin in the TextBlock's coordinates
        Point relativePoint = textblock.RenderTransformOrigin;
        double reference = relativePoint.X * textblock.ActualWidth;

        // the relative offset of the 2 values above will move the TextBlock's origin to an "absolute" position
        return offset.X - reference;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The above does the transform for X only, but you can extend it to do both X and Y by using a separate converter class for each coordinate.

---

One note about the above:  the transformation will only run once, on load.  If the TextBlock is moving around, and you need to perform the transformation continuously, then you might have to get creative. :)

Comment: But I am wondering , text placement is an important feature and how it is placed in the absolute point correctly, something like Moveto (5,5)

Comment: @Robin I'm not following your comment ... I thought you wanted to sort of "drag" a relative point within the TextBlock to an absolute position in the Window?

Comment: @@McGarnagle, No no, I just wanted to move the textblock (Assume center point is the reference now) to certain position in the canvas. It may be (5,10) or something else. When I say move to (5,10) the textblock should be moved to (5,10) which means the center reference point at (5,10)...

Comment: @Robin right, that was my understanding.  I believe the above approach does this (well, only for the X coordinate, but it should be the right principle).

Comment: @@McGarnagle, Thanks I will try that and mark it as an answer. Btw why this process is so complex in WPF? I am from Winform side and getting my head around WPF now :-)