# Textblock dyanmic placement WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, wpf-controls, textblock

I have a text data. I would like to place the data dynamically to a certain point [Absolute point, it may be (0,0) (10,10) or (100,100)].

Here the problem comes. My requirement is text block's center point should be the base point. How to make it and place it directly on the canvas? [Which means align the absolute point and center point of the textblock]. Because in winforms we can set the alignment property and place it directly. [Please check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000804/wpf-textblock-translation-based-on-reference-point) .It describes how to move the textblock after placing it on the canvas since actual width can be  found.

I have two specific questions

1. Is it possible to do it in WPF
2. Is there anyway to find the actual width before placement, in case I can do it as in the other question

Update (Further explanation)::::: This is my Data Template to place the text, I can use TranslateTransform to translate the text as soon as the text is placed on the canvas by using MoveToPoint function mention below.

The real problem come, how to pass the ActualWidth to MoveToPoint inside datatemplate,

XAML

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Text}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"
               FontSize= "{Binding Thickness}" 
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
               Foreground="#FFF63AFF" 
               FontWeight="Bold" >       
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <TranslateTransform X= "{Binding StartPoint.X}" Y= "{Binding StartPoint.Y}"  />                   
                <RotateTransform Angle= "{Binding Angle}"  />
            </TransformGroup>   
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>  
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

C#

```
void MoveToPoint(UIElement sender, Point point)
{
    Canvas.SetLeft(sender, point.X - sender.RenderTransformOrigin.X * sender.ActualWidth);
    Canvas.SetTop(sender, point.Y - sender.RenderTransformOrigin.Y * sender.ActualHeight);
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use the answer provided in previous question? If you want to place it directly on the canvas, you need to create everything in the code-behind.

Comment: Do you need this to align the text box with other controls?

Comment: When is the certain point set? Also everything is possible in WPF. Depending on what you are actually trying to do it sounds like you need a custom panel and need to read up on WPFs layout cycle: Measure and Arrange

Comment: @MaximBalaganskiy What you mean by that? If I place the textblock at certain location, that's fine for me

Comment: @Robin: If the task is just to align a label and a text box, so that they are on the same base line, then I would place them in some container (Grid or StackPanel) and set their VerticalAlignment=True and Height=Auto. Otherwise, I would create a custom Canvas control which can position text boxes based on the font's baseline properties.

As for your second question, yes, you can call the control's Measure method to find out how much space it needs.

Comment: @MaximBalaganskiy, my requirement is not alignment. Placing the textcontrol in a certain location based on textcontrol's center point. by default textcontrol's base point is in top left corner. I will try control's Measure method as you mention

Comment: 2Robin: You could also try a translate transform on the control.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54690/discussion-between-robin-and-maxim-balaganskiy).

Comment: This shows the sample implementation to my question under Using a Multi-Binding Converter.http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/centering-text-within-a-wpf-shape-using-a-canvas. I will post the answer soon