# Accessing Canvas properties inside DataTemplate, WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, datatemplate

I have a DataTemplate for text and I use an ItemControl to place the text inside a canvas. How to access canvas properties inside the data template? In case if it is difficult I want to access individual textbox properties inside ItemControl. The reason is I need to do some textcontrol alignment. Both of my DataTemplate and ItemControl code is below

```
<DataTemplate
    DataType="{x:Type local:Text}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"
               FontSize= "{Binding Thickness}" 
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
               Foreground="#FFF63AFF" 
               FontWeight="Bold" >  
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <TranslateTransform X= "{Binding StartPoint.X}" Y= "{Binding StartPoint.Y}"  />                   
            <RotateTransform Angle= "{Binding Angle}"  />
        </TransformGroup>   
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>  
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>  


<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path = TextList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate> 
            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Width="0" Height="0">  
                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>                     
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>                                
                </TransformGroup>
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            </Canvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to customize the layout of an ItemsControl's children and the available Panels don't deliver what you need, you will probably have to build your own panel. Here is an introduction to the topic: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15705/FishEyePanel-FanPanel-Examples-of-custom-layout-pa

The difficulty depends on what your layout will look like. Inside your panel you can then access all elements properties for layout logic. For Example if you wanted to align all multiline textboxes on the right side of the panel and all single line textboxes left, that would be easy to do. :)

If you elaborate a little more what you want to achieve I can give you better guidance.

---- EDIT ---
Canvas.Left and the others are AttachedProperties. You can for example bind against the assigned values inside the template using the following syntax:

```
MyProperty="{Binding Path=(Canvas.Left), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

---- EDIT 2 ---

So here's a Sample that should do what you want. In the ViewModel there's a Collection containing Points (X & Y). These get rendered inside an ItemsControl with a Canvas Panel. The tricky part is that around each element there's a ContentPresenter, so binding Canvas values to the Button in the ItemTemplate does not work. Therefore I added the ItemContainerStyle:

MainWindow.Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="Point">
                <Button Content="{Binding}" Width="40" Height="20" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"
                    Value="{Binding X}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"
                    Value="{Binding Y}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.Xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            Locations = new ObservableCollection<Point>
            {
                new Point(10,10),
                new Point(20,20),
                new Point(30,30),
                new Point(50,60),
            };
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Point> Locations { get; set; }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Support

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion

    }
```

Try that, I believe it should do what your are looking for. :)

Comment: @@Gope Actually I want to place the textcontrols in certain location(absolute positions) inside a canvas. It is a continuation of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904132/textblock-dyanmic-placement-wpf.

Comment: Do you think, custom panel is the right solution for my requirement

Comment: It depends, what's your problem with using Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top? If you only need to assign a place for some textboxes use the attached properties like Canvas.Left. If it gets more complicated then that you will need a custom panel or a helper class iterating over all elements and moving them to the right position (which is essentially what a panel does).

Comment: Just in case this is not clear. You can bind Canvas.Top and the other properties to any data and use a converter to calculate the final position. In case you need the canvas size for it to work and converterparameters are not bindable, you can derive your converter from dependencyobject, give a dependencyproperty and bind that in your view to the canvas size. This should work.

Comment: I edited my answer. It shows you how to access an AttachedProperty via Binding inside a Template.

Comment: @@Gope, awesome, I hope one before last comment is most suitable for me to proceed. I will try to implement other methods too. Could you please share if any sample implementation?. It will help me to reduce the implementation time.Anyhow I will share my answer

Comment: 'built a sample showing how to position Buttons inside a canvas just from a given List of Points. See my answer above (Edit 2) :)

Comment: is there any way to accees Canvas's actual width inside  <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">?, I need that one too

Comment: Yes, you can access it, but the question is what you need alltogether. If you define the canvas as a resource you can use it inside the ItemsPanel and the Style as well.
Be more specific about your concrete need and I will try to help you.