# Multibinding WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am arranging few textblocks in a canvas based on it's locations. sample code snippet is provided below at bottom. For this process I need to access each textblock's Actualwidth and Actual Height inside ItemContainerStyle. I am struggling to access it's properties as below by element name, because it doesn't have a name. How to do it? Do I need to do through templates?

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BPositionConverter}" ConverterParameter="Left">                            
     <Binding ElementName="TextBlock" Path="ActualHeight" />  <---Problem
     <Binding ElementName="TextBlock"  Path="ActualWidth" />  <---Problem
</MultiBinding>
```

--Full snippet

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="Point">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Width="40" Height="20" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>  
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">  
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BPositionConverter}" ConverterParameter="Left">                            
                        <Binding ElementName="TextBlock" Path="ActualHeight" />  <---Problem
                        <Binding ElementName="TextBlock"  Path="ActualWidth" />  <---Problem
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: could you tell us what you are trying to achieve? seems like you want to manipulate Canvas.Left, so wondering what does BPositionConverter does with the ActualHeight and ActualWidth. May there is another approach without specifying name to the textblock

Comment: @pushpraj, please check this question. It says all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000804/wpf-textblock-translation-based-on-reference-point  Actually it is for setting textpox position in a canvas based on the reference point, still I need to add some more parameters to multibinding converter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data template consist of a single text element you can refer to self to get the actual width and height for the same

so remove the ElementName and apply RelativeSource, should work with this trick

```
<Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BPositionConverter}"
                          ConverterParameter="Left">
                <Binding Path="ActualHeight"
                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                <Binding Path="ActualWidth"
                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't think it in this way,I will. what happens if there are more elements?

Comment: this will account the whole layout in the data template and actual width or height will respond accordingly, other approach is to use properties in your model and push the values from textblock and retrieve them in style if only textblock is needed.

Comment: it always returns zero, what is the reason?

Comment: For my tests using the data template mentioned in question, it works fine. You may perhaps check if there is any binding or data error in output window. Is it possible for you to share a working sample of your concerned piece of code? for minimum the BPositionConverter and the data model (eg Location).